# Enter key in KeyDown

Tags: vb.net

I just started learning VB recently and I'm trying to get familiar with the methods. Here I'm trying to write the key code to the console each time I press a key.

```
Private Sub kd(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
```

This work for most of the keys, but strangely I can't get <kbd>Enter</kbd> to work. One thing I noticed is that whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I also "clicked" one of the buttons I have in the form.

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you have the KeyPreview property of the form set to True?

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I did.

Answer (score 0):

Keys like Shift, Enter, Tab, Escape are special keys. They need a little different commands.

```
Private Sub Form2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        MsgBox("Success!")
    End If
End Sub
```

And that button which you are talking about has the focus. Set the focus to the form using `SetFocus` Control

That should work perfectly!

Comment: How do you set focus to the form? I tried `Me.Focus()` but the button still receives focus.

Comment: Learn the active control property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

User Your Controls Key Down Event and Check for Keys to be Enter

```
Private Sub kd(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
     IF e.key=key.Enter Then
       <do your code>
     Endif
End Sub
```